# Camera Result always returns RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to take pictures with my camera. I just need them temporally so i do the following:

```
private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(this.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            this.imageFile = File.createTempFile("CROP_SHOT", ".jpg", this.getActivity().getCacheDir());

            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(this.imageFile));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

            this.startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the result code `RESULT_CANCELED` in my `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult");

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult take photo");

            this.startCropImage(Uri.fromFile(this.imageFile));
        } else if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) {
            Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult pick photo");

            this.startCropImage(data.getData());
        } else if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO) {
            Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult crop photo");

            this.imageEncoded = data.getStringExtra(Globals.KEY_IMAGE_ENCODED);

            this.imageView.setImageBitmap(Images.decodeImage(imageEncoded));
            this.buttonSave.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult requestCode: " + requestCode + ", result: " + resultCode);
        }
    } else {
        Log.v("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult resultCode is not ok: " + resultCode);
    }
}
```

Every solutions i found so far on stackoverflow and in the web did not solve my problem. I use the cache directory for creating a temp file:

```
File.createTempFile("CROP_SHOT", ".jpg", this.getActivity().getCacheDir());
```

And i have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Picking images from my smartphone always works fine:

```
private void pickPicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    this.startActivityForResult(intent, Globals.REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO);
}
```

So why is the camera always returning `RESULT_CANCELED`?

It is appearing on Nexus 4 with Android 6.0 and on Samsung Galaxy S III with Android 4.2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I use the cache directory for creating a temp file:

First, a third-party camera app has no rights to work with your app's private cache directory on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Second, you are not supposed to create the file. The camera app is supposed to create the file. Some camera apps may get confused and refuse to overwrite your file.

So, create a `File` object pointing to a location on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) (e.g., `getExternalCacheDir()`), but do not create the file yet. Use that `File` object as the basis for your `EXTRA_OUTPUT` value.

Also note that `MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY` is for recording videos; it has no meaning for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Agree that a new file should not be created. Not sure why google training doc creates a temporary file prior to creating the URI that will be used by the camera app via the FileProvider. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent

Comment: Just simply instantiating a file pointing to external cache dir doesn't help. The stock cam doesn't respond when we click to use the picture.

Answer (score 2):

What @CommonsWare mentioned is right, but if you still want to follow what the official documentation said, what I did was granting those 3rd party applications, which are able to handle your intent, a temporary read and write URI permissions:

```
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedIntentActivities = getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takePhotoIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolvedIntentInfo : resolvedIntentActivities) {
    String packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    getContext().grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

The above code snippet should be inserted before your `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the FileProvider. So your app don't need any permission to write to external storage and your app can grant the camera the permission to write to the

Start the camera with permission to use app folders:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getPhotoFile(context));
camera.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
camera.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

public static Uri getPhotoFile(Context context) {
    File file = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), "camera.jpg");
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider.files", file);
}
```