# Error in method getUriForFile - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I've been working on a simple Android application that takes a picture and stores it in the app's directory. I've followed Android Developpers tutorials exactly but i'm still getting an error.

I've seen lots of questions about this error in StackOverflow, but none of them seen to fix my error.

This is the logcat error I get:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting, PID: 31539
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting/files/Pictures/JPEG_20170914_014854_-551864997.jpg
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
at com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:124)
at com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:43)
at com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:81)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

This is the method where I call getUriForFile:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("Erro", "no ceateImageFile() : "+ex);
        }

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method I create the file:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml snippet:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature   android:name="android.hardware.camera"
                android:required="true" />
```

file_paths.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path 
    name="my_images" 
path="Android/data/com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting/files/Pictures/" />
    </paths>
```

Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: Try adding Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and check

Comment: path set  context.getFilesDir().getPath();  this get your root directory

Comment: `path="Android/data/com.example.victormaruca.gpstesting/files/Pictures/"`. Change to `path="."`.

Comment: try this may work: <external-path name="external_files" path="."/> in your file_paths.xml

Comment: check this https://github.com/raghunandankavi2010/SamplesAndroid/tree/master/StackOverFlowTest. Also read commonsware answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272403/camera-result-always-returns-result-canceled

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Change your *file_paths.xml* to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
      name="my_images"
      path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

**Additional thoughs**

I guess you followed the official article how [to take photos on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java). The example here *res/xml/file_paths.xml* confuses. Fox example:

```
<!-- Not working. According to the docs. -->
<external-files-path 
    name="my_images"
    path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />

<!-- Works -->
<external-files-path
    name="my_images"
    path="Pictures" />

<!-- Also works -->
<external-files
    name="my_images"
    path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
```

I found a solution [here in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPHkhamDoyc).

Plus, have a look at the source code of the method
*FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile* which you use. When you debug the source code you can see how it builds the Uri and why it may throw IllegalArgumentException. It can lead to a solution as well.

Source code:

```
        ...
        // Find the most-specific root path
        Map.Entry<String, File> mostSpecific = null;
        for (Map.Entry<String, File> root : mRoots.entrySet()) {
            final String rootPath = root.getValue().getPath();
            if (path.startsWith(rootPath) && (mostSpecific == null
                    || rootPath.length() > mostSpecific.getValue().getPath().length())) {
                mostSpecific = root;
            }
        }

        if (mostSpecific == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Failed to find configured root that contains " + path);
        }
        ...
```